# Can I take protein shake instead of lunch?

Tags: workout, protein

I workout at the office from 11:45 AM to 12:30 PM. This helps me avoid disrupting official work hours. Now 12:30 PM is time for lunch. But what if I take my protein shake at 12:30 PM instead of lunch? And delay my lunch until two-three hours later. The lunch served at our office can not be considered a balance diet so I am afraid if I take lunch immediately after workout, I might be depriving my body from some key nutrients and protein when it most needs it (after workout).

Comment: While a workout is mentioned, this is a very broad question about personal nutrition. Unless you are doing cardio exercise, there isn't a lot of evidence that nutrient timing assists workouts. It's very much down to personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is quite broad and vague, but it has to be, because the question is broad and vague.

> Can I take protein shake instead of lunch?

Of course you can. The question is, should you?

There are ramifications to doing so. Unfortunately, I don't know which ramifications to cover, because you haven't given a single detail about yourself, your current status, your goals, your habits, your training regimen.

> The lunch served at our office can not be considered a balance diet

A single meal isn't supposed to provide a balanced diet. It's supposed to be *part* of a balanced diet. You have to consider if you need what it provides. If you don't, make your own lunch.

> so I am afraid if I take lunch immediately after workout

I assume from this part that you workout just before lunch? Again, missing a lot of information here.

> I might be depriving my body from some key nutrients and protein when it most needs it (after workout)

If you workout, and don't eat protein afterwards, the need for protein is still there. Your muscles don't suddenly stop needing protein after an hour.